# Delay second click until animate.css has completed animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, onclick, animate.css

I have an object that when clicked, it will fade off screen, when another object is clicked, it will fade back into the screen.

Once the object has faded away, the attribute Visibility:hidden is applied, but before the object comes back, the visibility is set to visible, before the animation plays out. Otherwise it simply pops on screen.

The problem is, when you click the object too fast, before the previous animation completes, the previous visibility is not reverted, thus two objects end up hidden.

I've provided my current working code. This works perfectly, so long as you take your time clicking the objects, but breaks if you click too fast.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log("[debug] - Script loaded ...")

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                   Variables                  //              
//////////////////////////////////////////////////

    var allCards = $(".card")
    var selectedCard
    var animationEnded
    var removeClasses = "animated fadeOutUp fadeInDown"
    var pullCardOut = "selected-card animated fadeOutUp"
    var putCardBack = "animated fadeInDown"

// Assign a unique ID Number to each card ...
    allCards.attr('id', function(i) {
        console.log("[debug] - Assigned " + (i+1) + " cards a unique ID.")
        return 'card'+(i+1);
    });

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                  Card Click                  //              
//////////////////////////////////////////////////

    allCards.click(function(event){   
        // Get the unique ID of which card was clicked and store it in "cardClicked" variable ...
        var cardClicked = event.target.id;
        var selectedCard = $("#" + cardClicked)
        var animationEnded = "webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend"
        var previouslySelectedCard = null

        // Dump the clicked card to the console ...
        // console.log("[debug] - cardClicked = "+cardClicked+" ...")
        console.log("[debug] - selectedCard = " + selectedCard + " ... (WHAT?)")
        console.log("[debug] - " + cardClicked + " was clicked");

        // Find any current card that may already be the selected card,
        //   and remove the previously selected card, before selecting the new card.

        if ($("#all-cards").find("div.selected-card").length !== 0) {
            console.log("[debug] - Found a selected card")
            // Find the card number of the previously clicked card
            var previouslySelectedCard = $('.selected-card').attr('id');

            console.log("#" + previouslySelectedCard + " was previously selected")
            $("#" + previouslySelectedCard).css("visibility", "visible");
            $("#" + previouslySelectedCard).removeClass(pullCardOut).addClass(putCardBack).one(animationEnded, function() {

            });

        } else {
            console.log("[debug] - No cards currently selected")
        }


        //Step 2: Add the appropriate classes to fade the card up.
        //selectedCard.removeClass("selectedCard "+removeClasses);

        selectedCard.addClass(pullCardOut).one(animationEnded, function() {
            selectedCard.css("visibility", "hidden");
        });

        //Step 3: Return the card to the holder, if anywhere else on the page is clicked.
        //  Remove all associated classes and reset the state back to a refreshed page.
    });
```

});

I have a working model of my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/swox9a0y/3/ which might be easier to understand what is going on.

My question is, how can I disable clicking on a second object, until the initial fade out animation, and visibility has been set?

Comment: You can call the second animation as a callback when the first one completes. You can also add a delay in the function as a parameter. Promises and chains are two other options to make sure an event completes before another one starts.

Comment: The examples on api.jquery, only seem to cover .promise() when jquery animations are completed. When I add a promise call on my code, it fires right away, not when the animate.css is finished. Do you have any examples of using a .promise() without jquery animations?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a variable check to prevent re-clicking until the timeout is finished, or use a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

```
//Create a variable to track if element is animating
var elementIsAnimating = false;

//Inside click function, set the variable to true.
allCards.click(function(event){  

    //Check if element is animating
    if (!elementIsAnimating) { 

        ...

        selectedCard.addClass(pullCardOut).one(animationEnded, function() {
            selectedCard.css("visibility", "hidden");
            elementIsAnimating = false;
        });
        elementIsAnimating = true; //This executes right after the class is added, preventing any future clicks until it is false again.

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the **pointer-events** to "none" on the element being clicked, and revert it back to "auto" with the same timing as your animation. So if your animation lasts 1 second:

```
$('.my_button').click(function() {
    $(this).css('pointer-events', 'none')
    setTimeout(function() {
    $(this).css('pointer-events', 'auto')
    }, 1000)
})
```

This prevents any rapid firing of the click event.